# Build many projects with the same CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I've asked a similar question previously, but I guess it was badly worded, so here goes attempt 2.

I have the following structure in my project folder:

- `mainLib`

  - `include`

    - `mainLib.h`
- `CMakeLists.txt`
- `project1`

  - `project.cpp`
- `project2`

  - `project.cpp`
- ...
- `projectN`

  - `project.cpp`

All the projects (`project1`, ... `projectN`) use the same `mainLib` and I'd like them to also use the same `CMakeLists.txt` file from the root directory, without creating a separate in each folder - and out of necessity (because of access to the mainLib) - calling them from the `CMakeLists.txt` in the main directory.

**Important thing**: the number of projects can change, so I'd like to build them passing the directory name to `CMakeLists.txt` or something in this spirit, rather than having to define them apriori in `CMakeLists.txt`.

In effect of running the main `CMakeLists.txt` I'd like to have just:

- `projectN`

  - `project.cpp`
  - `project.o`

In each project directory.

Bonus points for making the CMakeLists.txt swallow a `*.cpp` file of any name from the `projectN` directory and calling the output binary using the name of the `*.cpp` file.

Bonus bonus points: for telling me how to make the build folders automatically disappear after the cmake installation has been finished.

[Here's my previous attempt, that I've mentioned at the beginning, that I think is likely to break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68320473/making-similar-subprojects-group-of-projects-with-cmake-at-demand)

Comment: I usually have a root CMakeLists.txt and a  CMakeLists.txt for each executable and each library. And there is no issue using libraries. Only the root CMakeLists.txt has a project() all other CMakeLists.txt do not.

Comment: @drescherjm that's what I've noticed, but my inner minimalist tells me it can be done without those extra files.

Comment: @Ranza your inner minimalist is kinda right. You can create the CMakeLists.txt file for all the projects in their respective root directories, then you can create a bash script in the directory where all the projects are stored which calls CMake for all the projects. I can post this as an answer if you like this solution

Comment: If your given question is about the same problem as the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68320473/making-similar-subprojects-group-of-projects-with-cmake-at-demand), then why don't you edited the previous question instead? This is a proper way on Stack Overflow. You previous question has at least some code, the current one has no code, and this is bad. And again you ask **many questions** in one. (Well, actually there is no questions, these are requirements). Just take a requirement, and try to apply it. On success, move to the next. On fail ask, but show your attempt too.

Comment: Do you want many projects(actually, executables) to be described in the same `CMakeLists.txt`? - No problem, just add them into the same `CMakeLists.txt`. If you thing that adding a new project requires many copy-pasted code, then mode that code into the macro/function, and call it for every project. "the number of projects can change, so I'd like to build them passing the directory name to `CMakeLists.txt` or something in this spirit" - No problem, you may create a parameter to `cmake` and check that parameter in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Once again: just **try** to implement what you want.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how CMake works.

1. You are supposed to have a CMakeLists.txt in every folder you have source files. There are tricks to reduce the number of CMakeLists.txt files, but they are just tricks and this might result in more code, less readable code or even subtle bugs, when not done right.
2. You should make an out-of-source build. This means you have to create a folder in the root directory of your project or even outside of it. Then call `cmake` there and the last argument is the path to your root directory of the source code. Then everything generated by CMake is located below the build directory and your source directory is not polluted. After installation, you can delete the build directory and you achieve what you wanted.

For your question regarding the library and cpp stuff, they might be good questions of their own. I first wanted to address your CMake misconceptions. You should not work against your build system, but let it do the work for you.